# How to send an array with pdo to use it in html_options of smarty 3.1.21

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, smarty

I'm updating a section that uses MySQL to **PDO** to show an `{html_options}` of **Smarty**. This code works well actually with MySQL, but I don't know how to get same results using **PDO**.

This is the code that works well actually:

```
// Send states
$q="SELECT id, state FROM states";
$data=$db->execute($q);
$idStates=array();
$states =array();
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($data);$i++) {
    array_push($idStates,$data[$i]->id);
    array_push($states,$data[$i]->state);
}
$smarty->assign('idStates',$idStates);
$smarty->assign('states',$states);
```

Then all works well in the .tpl file

```
<select name="des_idState" class="form-control">
    <option>Select state</option>   
    {html_options output="$states" values="$idStates" selected=$data.idState}
</select>
```

What I am trying to do with PDO works well using `{foreach}`, but I need to use the `selected`, and I think is easiest doing with {html_options} of Smarty, but I don't know how to send the array from PDO.

```
$sql1="SELECT id, state FROM states";

$stmt = $dba->prepare($sql1); 
$stmt->execute(); 

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $idStates = $row['id'];
    $states = $row['state'];

    $smarty->assign('idStates', $idStates);
    $smarty->assign('states',$states);
}
```

I have been trying with this code that shows me the array using `echo $idStates . ' ' . $states . '<br>';`, however it doesn't work in the {html_options}, nothing shown, no error, just a blank space.

Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it has been a while since this question was posted, but did you ever find a solution to your problem? I believe you could fix the **id** and **state** variables to be arrays with minimal code modifications.

In the example below, I have added id and state array declarations at the beginning to ensure that the arrays are empty (as a precaution for the next step). I then changed `$idStates=` to `$idStates[]=` and `$states=` to `$states[]=`, which will add the current value to those arrays on each loop. Last, I moved the smarty variable assignments to be after the while loop so that the arrays will be fully populated. Here is the modified code:

```
$sql1="SELECT id, state FROM states";

$stmt = $dba->prepare($sql1); 
$stmt->execute(); 

$idStates = array();
$states = array();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $idStates[] = $row['id'];
    $states[] = $row['state'];
}

$smarty->assign('idStates', $idStates);
$smarty->assign('states',$states);
```

I have also included an alternative solution below that should return the same data. In this example, I use `$stmt->fetchAll` instead of `$stmt->fetch` to get all rows at once and then store them in an associative array. I then use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) when declaring the smarty assignments, which separates out the id and state columns from the `$rows` associative array. This results in a bit less code without sacrificing readability:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT id, state FROM states";

$stmt = $dba->prepare($sql1); 
$stmt->execute(); 

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$smarty->assign('idStates', array_column($rows, 'id'));
$smarty->assign('states', array_column($rows, 'states'));
```